# Do we really need a functional object for applying prototype methods in javascript? if yes than why ?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, prototype

As I can see in the question ['How does JavaScript .prototype work?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) the correct way to use the `prototype` property is with a functional object. But I am not able to understand  why we need a functional object to use `prototype`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "functional object."  As opposed to what?

Comment: Why? because JavaScipt. :)

Comment: @Explosion Pills   , This word is used in the question that I referred ,have a look on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a function in JavaScript, the interpreter automatically creates a prototype object for it. This is because functions can be used as constructors.

**Only functions and no other object can be used as a constructor.**

That's the reason only functions have a `prototype` property. The `prototype` property of a function is very special. Instances of that function will have the prototype of the function in their `__proto__` chain.

Read this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question you referred

```
var obj = new Object(); // not a functional object
obj.prototype.test = function() { alert('Hello?'); }; // this is wrong!
```

That's because `Object` is the base class for all.

```
function MyClass() {

}
var obj = new MyClass();

// it returns true even though its an instance of MyClass
console.log(obj instanceof Object);
```

If you add a prototype function to `Object` class, you need to make sure that its non-enumerable.

Comment: Of course you can add prototype methods to `Object`! However, you need to care about making them non-enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

> why we need a functional object for prototype?

It was an odd(?) language design decision in early JS versions. Yet this was fixed with EcmaScript 5: [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) allows us to do prototypical inheritance without constructor functions. So if you don't [need an initialisation function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11253717/1048572) (as a closure for example), you happily can [use "Object.create" instead of "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709612/1048572).