# can't use Object.create to create object inside an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Let's say I have the following code:

```
(function($) {
    var Obj = {
        init: function() {
            var c1 = Object.create(this.MyChild);
            var c2 = Object.create(this.MyChild);
            c1.init(); //not working!!!
        },
        MyChild: function() {
            this.init = function() {
                console.log('calling MyChild init function');   
            }
        }
    };

    Obj.init();
})(jQuery);
```

When creating Obj, I used object literal as I don't need to create the instance of it, and when creating MyChild objects, I used the constructor function and used Object.create as I need to create multiple instances of MyChild.

However, when I call Object.create, it doesn't work, when c1.init() is called, it says the init function is undefined, but if I replaced Object.create(this.MyChild) to:

```
var c1 = new this.MyChild(); 
c1.init();
```

why?

Comment: `Object.create` is *not* a replacement for `new`! What's wrong with calling the constructor?

Comment: @Bergi I thought they are pretty much the same, it's just I have read some articles saying that "Object.create" should be used when creating the instance, instead of using "new". I think I'll just stick with var c1 = new this.MyChild();

Comment: Screw those articles. You can use `Object.create` when you don't need initialisation, and you should use it when you must not use initialisation. Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11253826/1048572, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14267886/1048572 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.create(func)` doesn't do the same thing as `new func()`!

`Object.create()` creates an (otherwise empty!) object, which prototype will be set to the object, that is passed to that function ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create))

To use `Object.create()` in your example, you could modify it like this:

```
(function($) {
    var Obj = {
        init: function() {
            var c1 = Object.create(this.MyChild);
            var c2 = Object.create(this.MyChild);
            c1.init(); //not working!!!
        },
        MyChild: {
            init: function() {
                console.log('calling MyChild init function');   
            }
        }
    };

    Obj.init();
})(jQuery);
```

But in this case everything will just POINT to your `MyChild` object. Properties of `MyChild` will be shared among every object, that you create using `Object.create()`.

Comment: @cookiemonster: The constructor function into what is appropriate here. +1

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I see it now. I was focused on the first `init`. Though the constructor isn't what changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
var c1 = Object.create(this.MyChild.prototype);
```

instead of

```
var c1 = Object.create(this.MyChild);
```

Comment: Still, it would not have an `init` method then.